# enumdisplayDevices returns multiple instances for one display card

Tags: c++, registrykey

Hi I am using the following code fragment to get number of display adapters in my windows 7 system. I have a NVidia GT 120 which is connected to my monitor, and a NVidia Quadro 4000 which is acting as my GPU processor.

Because both display adapters have more than one output port, with following code, I actually get 2 Display_Device instances for GT120 and 2 for Quadro 4000. My work around of this problem is actually using the DeviceKey component (which MSDN says is not used, but it is in fact a registry key) of the DisplayDevice structure as criteria to remove the duplicate instance.

Did anyone has a better, or official solution to this problem?

```
FARPROC EnumDisplayDevices;
HINSTANCE  hInstUser32;
DISPLAY_DEVICE DispDev; 
char szSaveDeviceName[32];
BOOL bRet = TRUE;

hInstUser32 = LoadLibrary("User32.DLL");
if (!hInstUser32) return FALSE;  

// Get the address of the EnumDisplayDevices function
EnumDisplayDevices = (FARPROC)GetProcAddress(hInstUser32,"EnumDisplayDevicesA");
if (!EnumDisplayDevices) {
    FreeLibrary(hInstUser32);
    return FALSE;
}

ZeroMemory(&DispDev, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
DispDev.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE); 

// After the first call to EnumDisplayDevices, 
// DispDev.DeviceString is the adapter name
while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, nDeviceIndex++, &DispDev, 0)) {  
    //getdevice
} 
FreeLibrary(hInstUser32);

return bRet;
```